# I want to have two periods in the fullcalendar defined by slotMinTime and slotMaxTime

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I intended to use two different periods in the same calendar. The only way to do it that I've found so far is to do it in two different calendars, where it looks like this:

```js
$(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el = $(this).data('element');
  $(el).show();
  $("section > div").not(el).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-visita', function(){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }else{
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }  

     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');
     var today = moment().day();

     var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        locale: "pt-br",

        buttonText:{
            today:    'Hoje',
            list:     'Lista'
        },

        navLinks: true,             
        firstDay: today,
        hiddenDays: [ 0 ],
        initialView: initialViews,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true, 
        unselectAuto:true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        eventColor: '#f16621', 
        slotDuration: '00:45',
        allDaySlot : false,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable:false,
        longPressDelay: 0,
        nowIndicator: "true",
        slotMinTime: '10:30',
        slotMaxTime: '12:00',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        
                

    });

    calendar.render();
});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-visita', function(){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }else{
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }  

     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario1');
     var today = moment().day();

     var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        locale: "pt-br",

        buttonText:{
            today:    'Hoje',
            list:     'Lista'
        },

        navLinks: true,             
        firstDay: today,
        hiddenDays: [ 0 ],
        initialView: initialViews,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true, 
        unselectAuto:true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        eventColor: '#f16621', 
        slotDuration: '00:45',
        allDaySlot : false,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable:false,
        longPressDelay: 0,
        nowIndicator: "true",
        slotMinTime: '14:30',
        slotMaxTime: '19:00',
        contentHeight: 'auto',

    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>

<a href="s160" data-element="#minhaDiv160" class="btn-show dad-visita">
    <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-info"></i>
    Consultar Visitas
</a>

<section id="s160">
  <div style="display:none;" id="minhaDiv160">
    <div class="cal-wrapper"><div id='calendario'></div></div>
    <div class="cal-wrapper"><div id='calendario1'></div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But this way I have to have two calendars, which is not the correct way. The reason I have to do this is that I need the slotDuration to be 45 minutes and in the morning it assumes the time of events correctly.

But the afternoon events start at 14:30 and with this slotDuration the calendar in the afternoon event starts at 14:15 if you set the slotMinTime at 10:30 and the slotMaxTime at 19:00, as shown in the example:

```js
$(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el = $(this).data('element');
  $(el).show();
  $("section > div").not(el).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-visita', function(){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }else{
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }  

     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');
     var today = moment().day();

     var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        locale: "pt-br",

        buttonText:{
            today:    'Hoje',
            list:     'Lista'
        },

        navLinks: true,             
        firstDay: today,
        hiddenDays: [ 0 ],
        initialView: initialViews,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true, 
        unselectAuto:true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        eventColor: '#f16621', 
        slotDuration: '00:45',
        allDaySlot : false,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable:false,
        longPressDelay: 0,
        nowIndicator: "true",
        slotMinTime: '10:30',
        slotMaxTime: '19:00',
        contentHeight: 'auto',

    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>

<a href="s160" data-element="#minhaDiv160" class="btn-show dad-visita">
    <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-info"></i>
    Consultar Visitas
</a>

<section id="s160">
  <div style="display:none;" id="minhaDiv160">
    <div class="cal-wrapper"><div id='calendario'></div></div>
    <div class="cal-wrapper"><div id='calendario1'></div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

When starting at 14:15, it soon returns the times of all the different afternoon events with what I want.

I still couldn't find a solution to solve this problem.

**Code with selectAllow:**

```js
$(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el = $(this).data('element');
  $(el).show();
  $("section > div").not(el).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-visita', function(){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }else{
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }  

     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');
     var today = moment().day();

     var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        locale: "pt-br",

        buttonText:{
            today:    'Hoje',
            list:     'Lista'
        },

        navLinks: true,             
        firstDay: today,
        hiddenDays: [ 0 ],
        initialView: initialViews,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true, 
        unselectAuto:true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        eventColor: '#f16621', 
        slotDuration: '00:15',
        allDaySlot : false,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable:false,
        longPressDelay: 0,
        nowIndicator: "true",
        slotMinTime: '10:30',
        slotMaxTime: '19:00',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        
        select: function(start, end) {
            var start1 = moment((start.startStr)).format('HH:mm:ss');
            if(start1 == '14:15:00'){            
             
            $('#ModalAddVisit #start').val(moment((start.startStr)).format('YYYY-MM-DD' + " " + '14:30:00'));
            $('#ModalAddVisit #end').val(moment((start.startStr)).format('YYYY-MM-DD' + " " + '15:15:00'));
            $("#ModalAddVisit").modal("show");
            }

            
        },

    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="s160" data-element="#minhaDiv160" class="btn-show dad-visita">
    <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-info"></i>
    Consultar Visitas
</a>

<section id="s160">
  <div style="display:none;" id="minhaDiv160">
    <div class="cal-wrapper"><div id='calendario'></div></div>
  </div>
</section>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="ModalAddVisit" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">NOVA VISITA</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" class="row g-3 insvisit">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <label for="start"> <strong>DATA/HORA INICIAL</strong> <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="start" id="start" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <label for="end"> <strong>DATA/HORA FINAL</strong> <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="end" id="end" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary validatevisit" id="save-event">Gravar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @jcollum Hello, I found your suggestion interesting. So I updated my code and created a new question

Comment: `I need the slotDuration to be 45 minutes`...why, exactly? Why can't you have a smaller slot duration? If you need to restrict users to only selecting 45-minute blocks of time, there are other ways to achieve that.

Comment: @ADyson  yes, I need to restrict to 45 minute blocks. What are other ways to do it, can you explain?

Comment: Well for example you could use code via the [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) callback to check the length of the selection as the user is making it

Comment: @ADyson I've already added the code, but when I click to start the event from 2:30 pm to 3:15 pm, it always starts at 2:15 pm and ends at 3:00 pm. That is the problem

Comment: @ADyso Your suggestion in the answer, was this what you were referring to?

Comment: `It always starts at 2:15 pm and ends at 3:00 pm`...yes, because you haven't made the slots small enough so that you can select more specific times, which is what I was suggesting. You also haven't used `selectAllow` anywhere at all, even in your last example. Did you paste the wrong code??

Comment: @ADyso what I understood was this, can you put an example of how to apply the selectallow?

Comment: `selectAllow: function(info) { /*your calculation code goes here..., then at the end you have to return true or false */ return result; }`

Comment: @ADyso I can't put the smallest slots, because if I do it later it doesn't select the start and end correctly automatically, because each event is 45 minutes

Comment: @ADyso Now I can't test it, but I think I found a solution to solve the problem, I'll post it in the question shortly. I think I can create some conditions in the code I posted. I still don't understand what selectallow does

Comment: @ADyson See the change I made to the last code I posted in the question. this is the solution

Comment: @ADyson I await your opinion on the solution I found. I think it's the best for what I want

Comment: Surely that's a solution only for 1 time of day...

Comment: `I can't put the smallest slots, because if I do it later it doesn't select the start and end correctly automatically, because each event is 45 minutes`...that's the whole point of using selectAllow - you can check the time difference between start and end, and if it's not 45 minutes, you return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FullCalendar doesn't let you set two different min and max values on the same calendar.

To work round this, but still achieve your goal of enforcing 45-minute slots, with a break in the middle of day where no events can be created, you can

- reduce the [slotDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration) back to 15 minutes, and
- use [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) to restrict the length of time period the user can actually select, and
- mark the unavailable period(s) using [businessHours](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours) and use [selectConstraint](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint) to ensure users cannot add events during that period.

```js
$(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el = $(this).data('element');
  $(el).show();
  $("section > div").not(el).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-visita', function() {
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
  } else {
    initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
  }

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');
  var today = moment().day();

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    locale: "pt-br",
    buttonText: {
      today: 'Hoje',
      list: 'Lista'
    },
    navLinks: true,
    firstDay: today,
    hiddenDays: [0],
    initialView: initialViews,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    unselectAuto: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    eventColor: '#f16621',
    slotDuration: '00:15',
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventStartEditable: false,
    eventDurationEditable: false,
    longPressDelay: 0,
    nowIndicator: "true",
    slotMinTime: '10:30',
    slotMaxTime: '19:00',
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    selectConstraint: "businessHours",
    selectAllow: function(info) {
      var start = moment(info.start);
      var end = moment(info.end);
      var diff = end.diff(start, 'minutes');
      return (diff == 45);
    },
    businessHours: [
      {
        daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        startTime: '10:00',
        endTime: '12:00'
      },
      {
        daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        startTime: '14:30',
        endTime: '19:00'
      }
    ],
    select: function(info) {
      var start1 = moment((info.startStr)).format('HH:mm:ss');
      $('#ModalAddVisit #start').val(moment((info.startStr)).format('YYYY-MM-DD' + " " + '14:30:00'));
      $('#ModalAddVisit #end').val(moment((info.startStr)).format('YYYY-MM-DD' + " " + '15:15:00'));
      $("#ModalAddVisit").modal("show");
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="s160" data-element="#minhaDiv160" class="btn-show dad-visita">
  <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-info"></i> Consultar Visitas
</a>

<section id="s160">
  <div style="display:none;" id="minhaDiv160">
    <div class="cal-wrapper">
      <div id='calendario'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="ModalAddVisit" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">NOVA VISITA</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" class="row g-3 insvisit">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <label for="start"> <strong>DATA/HORA INICIAL</strong> <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="start" id="start" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <label for="end"> <strong>DATA/HORA FINAL</strong> <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="end" id="end" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary validatevisit" id="save-event">Gravar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```