# Merge two variables of new calendars in the render

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

This question might be a little weird but it would be the solution to the problem I have in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76661141/i-want-to-have-two-periods-in-the-fullcalendar-defined-by-slotmintime-and-slotma).

Is it possible to join two variables in render(). I will explain:

```js
$(".btn-show").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el = $(this).data('element');
  $(el).show();
  $("section > div").not(el).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-visita', function(){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }else{
          initialViews = 'timeGridWeek';
     }  

     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario');
     var today = moment().day();

     var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        locale: "pt-br",

        buttonText:{
            today:    'Hoje',
            list:     'Lista'
        },

        navLinks: true,             
        firstDay: today,
        hiddenDays: [ 0 ],
        initialView: initialViews,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true, 
        unselectAuto:true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        eventColor: '#f16621', 
        slotDuration: '00:45',
        allDaySlot : false,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable:false,
        longPressDelay: 0,
        nowIndicator: "true",
        slotMinTime: '10:30',
        slotMaxTime: '12:00',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        
                

    });
    
    var calendarr = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        locale: "pt-br",

        buttonText:{
            today:    'Hoje',
            list:     'Lista'
        },

        navLinks: true,             
        firstDay: today,
        hiddenDays: [ 0 ],
        initialView: initialViews,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true, 
        unselectAuto:true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        eventColor: '#f16621', 
        slotDuration: '00:45',
        allDaySlot : false,
        eventStartEditable: false,
        eventDurationEditable:false,
        longPressDelay: 0,
        nowIndicator: "true",
        slotMinTime: '14:30',
        slotMaxTime: '19:00',
        contentHeight: 'auto',

    });

    calendar.render();
    calendarr.render();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>

<a href="s160" data-element="#minhaDiv160" class="btn-show dad-visita">
    <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-info"></i>
    Consultar Visitas
</a>

<section id="s160">
  <div style="display:none;" id="minhaDiv160">
    <div class="cal-wrapper"><div id='calendario'></div></div>
    <div class="cal-wrapper"><div id='calendario1'></div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In the example I put I have the code to generate two calendars, one for the period from 10:30 to 12:00 and the other from 14:30 to 19:00. As in the end I have to render one at a time, it only shows the second calendar. Is it possible to render both at once, so that they are both within the same calendar? I tried like this:

```
calendar.calendarr.render();
```

But this does not generate any of the calendars

Comment: `Is it possible to render both at once, so that they are both within the same calendar`...you mean within the same HTML element? No, that makes no sense at all. One will just overwrite the other, as you've discovered. In your previous question I already gave you a possible solution to your original issue...did you try it?

Comment: @ADyson I've tried and tried to search but I couldn't implement what you suggested. Can you put an example for me to understand?

Comment: Go back to the original question and edit it to show what you tried so far, then I may be able to help you work on it. It should just be a case of getting the difference between two dates, and checking if it equals 45 minutes, or not.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, I'll add the code in the other question to see what I've done